# Perl or python regular expression split for pipe and quotes

Tags: regex, perl, split, pipe

I am trying to parse below string -

Input: `"1"|"abc xyz"||"a|25|30"|2345`

Output:

```
"1"
"abc xyz"

"a|25|30"
2345
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Save your sanity, use a CSV parser.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
#!perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Text::CSV;

my $in = q{"1"|"abc xyz"||"a|25|30"|2345};
my $csv = Text::CSV->new({ sep_char => '|', quote_char => '"' });
$csv->parse($in);
print $_, "\n" for $csv->fields;
```

### Output:

```
1
abc xyz

a|25|30
2345
```

Answer (score 1):

A CSV parser removes the quotes. These solutions keep them intact.

```
use Text::ParseWords qw(quotewords);
quotewords(qr'[|]', qr("), q("1"|"abc xyz"||"a|25|30"|2345));
# (
#     '"1"',
#     '"abc xyz"',
#     '',
#     '"a|25|30"',
#     2345
# )

use Data::Record qw();
use Regexp::Common qw(delimited);
my $r = Data::Record->new({ split => qr'[|]', unless => $RE{quoted} });
$r->records(q("1"|"abc xyz"||"a|25|30"|2345));
# (
#     '"1"',
#     '"abc xyz"',
#     '',
#     '"a|25|30"',
#     2345
# )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $input = q{"1"|"abc xyz"||"a|25|30"|2345||"2"|"z|6|7"|"jkl"||b};
print $& eq '||' ? "\n" : "$&\n" while $input =~ /".*?"|\w+|\|.{0}\|/g;
```

**Output**:

```
"1"
"abc xyz"

"a|25|30"
2345

"2"
"z|6|7"
"jkl"

b
```